# Friendly notifier for review questions with missing code?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

On occasion new users, unfamiliar with how code review works, would post a question for review without some sample of the actual code in question. I'd imagine this happens because the user wants to jump right in and starting asking rather than taking the time to read the FAQ. What ends up happening is they just provide a link to pastebin, github, bitbucket etc. in the question and expect reviewers to check it out or worse -- unpacking a zip file. Some of these [questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/does-this-small-project-conform-to-rest-principles) get closed while [others](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/opinions-on-asp-net-mvc-3-generator) [linger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/my-first-node-module-and-first-js-project) in [obscurity](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/please-review-iresign-my-first-mac-os-app-used-for-codesigning-of-ios-apps).

Adding a friendly pop-up reminder when new users post a question should help curb the occurrence of this situation. One way this could work is when the user clicks 'Post Your Question' perform a code check over the posted question. If no code is present then show a reminder and give the user a chance to amend their post. The simple message should let the user know that adding relevant code to your question will increase the likelihood for an answer.

What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I updated the How to Ask sidebar panel a bit:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Before:

> Share **code from projects you are working on for peer review.**
>
> Please specify what kind of feedback you're looking for: code correctness, best practices and design pattern usage, application UI, security issues, etc.

After:

> Share **code from projects you are working on for peer review.**
>
> The relevant code sections *must* be included in your question, though it is OK to link offsite to "see more".
>
> Please specify what kind of feedback you're looking for: code correctness, best practices and design pattern usage, application UI, security issues, etc.

The https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq is already quite clear on this point.

Answer (score 2):

You could flag the questions, and leave a comment, to include the code, and link to Jeffs improved text. A sentence why is fast typed, but a bulletpoint is better, since it can automatically provide the link.

I now made comments to said 3 posts and flagged them.